# list comprehension in if statement not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am trying to go through all files in a directory and do something to the files with specific filenames. For some reason, the if statement does not work when I use list comprehension and all iterations seem to go into the if statement:

```
for filename in os.listdir(somepath):
    if (str(i_test) in filename for i_test in range(15,20)):
        do something
```

The if-statement works as expected if I explicitly write the numbers in the if statement:

```
for filename in os.listdir(somepath):
    if '15' in filename or ('16' in filename) or ('17' in filename) or ('18' in filename) or ('19' in filename):
        do something
```

I couldn't find out where I messed up in the list comprehension.

Comment: `if any(str(i_test) in filename for i_test in range(15,20)):`

Comment: The problem you're running into is that your comprehension returns a generator object, boolean value of which is always true.

Comment: Also you could try: `if [i_test for i_test in range(15,20) if str(i_test) in filename]:`

Comment: @GiannisClipper There you are only playing *implicitely* with the fact that a non-empty list has a true boolean value. Better to explicitely check for presence in file like r.ook does. It reads better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a minor point, but that isn't a list comprehension; that's a generator expression. The difference here isn't substantial, but they are different. List comprehensions are wrapped in `[]`, while generator expressions use `()` (like you have here).

Second, you essentially have:

```
if <generator expression>:
```

The problem with that is a generator expression itself will never be false (unlike the result of a list comprehension), so that condition will always be true.

You want to use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to say "if any tests are true":

```
if any(str(i_test) in filename for i_test in range(15,20)):
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re`

```
import re

to_find = re.compile('|'.join(map(str, range(15,21)))

for filename in os.listdir(somepath):
    if to_find.search(filename):
        #do something
```